# Python run connexion based application inside functions or methods only

Tags: python-3.x, connexion

I have an application that uses connexion and swagger andd is quite large already. Just like in [examples](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/blob/master/examples/swagger2/sqlalchemy/app.py) of this framework, the connections to database are created outside of any function, or class. I find this approach as a really poor design, and I really feel like there should be one place (e.g. main()), where all the objects necessary are created and some .run() method is called on them.

The minimum I want is to have at least functions that are registered in swagger.yaml as endpoint handlers, to accept the database connection I provide, not one that has to be created on application start-up and available to all the functions.

Is there a way to achieve something like this, or do I have to make peace with having database connection created in one file and all the other files import it and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you cited, I view it as regrettable that we call
`orm.init_db('sqlite:///:memory:')` outside the If Main.
In the example it is harmless, but consider related cases like

1. sqlite:////tmp/pets.db or
2. TCP connection to DB server

The file cannot be safely `import`ed due to side effects -- it
leaves behind a .db file or it perhaps dies with connect error
if we lack creds or network connectivity.
This affects e.g. `$ python -m doctest`.
So I prefer to defer creating the connection until we actually need it,
which a singleton getter can easily do.
(Or have a class `__init__()` create the connection.)

---

For your app, rather than passing around global or parameter connection,
consider passing around a function object which can get the connection as needed.
It gives you a level of indirection, and admits of conditional processing.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. I really like  the idea of passing around a function object, instead of having it created  on file import. I was actually struggling with that, as for integration tests, I needed to first set environment variables and only then import the database object, which was just a hack for solving a poor design choices. Thank you!